# Scroll tableview cell in cube effect in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, tableview, cubes

Writing up an code for creating table view in such a manner when user scroll table view it behaves like cube. Please find below youtube link for the vision what I am asking for:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrBxHq83yKQ

Meanwhile, I tried with `CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 1, 0, 0);` and it working for adding up an row at the top but not for scrolling.

Further, due to lack of knowledge of OpenGLES I can not go with it for rotating the cubes with touch gesture. Please suggest for the same as per your feasibility.

Look forward to hear from you.

Comment: It could be done using a UIScrollView and OpenGL. You'll struggle any other way to do that sort of effect.

Comment: What is the reason for down-voting a question? Is it too simple or irrelevant?

Comment: No idea. Nothing to do with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for cubical scrolling. Earlier I was using below source code link:

[GestureBasedTableViewDemo](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo)

Meanwhile, above tableview demo was using gesture and allow me to only add first row in tableview cell while scrolling down but my requirement was to have cubical scrolling up or down both.

Further, I tried with vertical [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) cylindrical and I achieved the vertical cubical scrolling. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

check it out.. hope it helps you..

Link 1: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/abcustomuinavigationcontroller

Link 2: https://github.com/augustjoki/CubeTabBarController

Comment: I have already checked them. They are actually pushing the view controllers in horizontally manner and the requirement is scrolling vertically in cubical manner. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this effects with Layer transform and a scrollview. To build a cube take a look at this [post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/08/cubed-coreanimation-conundrum/). You might add some overlays to your cube-sides to simulate lightning and you are done.

Comment: It is actually implementing the core animation on the view. The requirement is render the data from the server via webservices and show it in tableview which I have accomplished. Now client asked for cubical scrolling for example there is 6 sides of cube so user can view 3 sides at time one is top, left and front. So if user scroll or swipe gesture on cube then next side will come up. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check our implementation of a gesture based 3D-cube over at Chubamobile:
http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/2106/Cube+Selector/

It's fully featured, ready to use out of the box - and pretty much exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps.

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 1;
    animation.type = @"cube";
    animation.subtype = @"fromRight";
    [self.contentView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];

    [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

or that link http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/objectivec-3d-view-rotation/

Don't dislike - there are few information about it.